# Regular expression negative replace?

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I need to get "yomomedia.com" if the HTTP_HOST is [ANY].yomomedia.com except in the cases where it is "dev.yomomedia.com" else it should return dev.yomomedia.com

```
echo preg_replace("/^([EVERYTHING-OTHER-THAN-DEV])\./Ui","",$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
```

Just tried the following with no success:

```
echo preg_replace("/^(?!dev)\./Ui",'','www.yomomedia.com'); // returns www.yomomedia.com
echo preg_replace("/^(?!dev)\./Ui",'','dev.yomomedia.com'); // returns dev.yomomedia.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A negative passive group (lookahead) should do:

```
/^(?!dev).*\./Ui
```

Comment: Now it should really work. There should have been .* after the lookahead. I've added it now

Comment: thanks, Ignas, I am yet to get into the realm of lookahead and lookbehind when it comes to regex

Answer (score 2):

[Look-arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) do not “consume” any characters. So your expression means the same as *the first three characters are not `dev`* (`^(?!dev)`) AND *the first character is a full stop* (`^\.`).

So try either this:

```
/^(?!dev\.)[^.]+\./Ui
```

Or:

```
/^[^.]+\.(?<!^dev\.)/Ui
```